# 7-Zip execution permissions on Windows Server 2008 64-bit

Tags: windows, 7zip

I've created a self-extracting 7-Zip file. There is one CMD file contained in it which 7-Zip runs on extract. This cmd reads the registry and performs some further activities (unimportant to this specific question).

In Windows Server 2003 32-bit this behavior works just fine. However, testing on a Windows Server 2008 box shows that the cmd kicked off by 7-Zip doesn't have permissions to read the registry. More specifically it can read some areas (Windows current version), but not others (other software keys).

If I take that cmd file and run it myself (running it from the temporary folder that 7-Zip extracts it to) everything runs fine.

Using UAC "Run as Administrator" produces the same issue, and disabling UAC doesn't seem to help.

I'm not aware of any 7-Zip options for the configuration file that tells it to escalate privileges, or anything like that. Is there something I'm missing here? Has registry access gotten more locked down in Windows Server 2008, or on a 64 bit version of the OS? How can I ensure that my EXE file can pass the right permissions to the command it kicks off?

Comment: Have you used the `<run-privileged/>` element in the installation XML file? [http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.htm](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the 7-Zip file is a 32-bit executable, your command script is running in a 32-bit context. One of the consequences is that certain registry locations are redirected. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

You can detect a WOW64 environment by looking for an environment variable, `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` and you can return to the native 64-bit environment by running the copy of `cmd.exe` found in `c:\windows\sysnative`.

These two lines at the top of your command file should do the trick:

```
if defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 c:\windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c %~pf0 %*
if defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 goto :eof
```

Comment: You sir are a wizard! I would have never stumbled onto this answer, thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Harry, I've found on win2k3 64 bit this trick doesn't work. Yes I've seen that sysnative doesn't exist there, and I need to swap to system32\cmd.exe, but when my script reruns there it still detects PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432. When I run system32\cmd.exe myself things work, but the swapover here seems to fail. Any idea what's up?

Comment: No, that won't work, that's still the 32-bit version.  The only solution I can think of at the moment would be to write a 64-bit application to relaunch your command file for you, and include it in the package.  Someone might be able to think of a cleverer answer if you post this as a new question ("How can 32-bit cmd.exe launch 64-bit cmd.exe in Windows 2003 x64?").

Comment: Spot on... I was looking for this for a while before I found it here.
It wasn't really clear to me that "sysnative" was the actual string I had to put there.  I initially tried substituting it with "system32" and it made my batch file run into an infinite loop. :)