# How can a 32-bit cmd.exe launch a 64-bit cmd.exe on Windows Server 2003 x64?

Tags: windows, cmd, 32bit-64bit

This is a follow up to *[7-Zip execution permissions on Windows Server 2008 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419023)*.

I'm trying to avoid having an overly complicated build process to make multiple 7-Zip EXE files. I just need a .cmd to kick off my Java process after reading some 64-bit registry entries. However, to succeed with a single EXE file, it needs to be 32 bit.

The above question found a trick for getting Windows Server 2008 to detect a 32 bit cmd.exe and swap it to 64 bit. Is there a way to do this on Windows Server 2003? There's a Windows hotfix that allows reg.exe to access 64-bit entries in 32-bit mode, but I can't be assured that's on the customer's server so that workaround is a no go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To launch 64-bit cmd.exe from 32-bit cmd.exe you must be able to access `c:\Windows\System32` folder without being redirected to `c:\Windows\SysWow64` folder. In Win2008 you can achieve this by accessing `c:\Windows\Sysnative` path. Unfortunately on Win2003 a hotfix is required (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589).

There is a workaround - you can create an NTFS junction point that directs to `c:\Windows\System32` folder and use path to that junction point instead of `c:\Windows\System32`. Using System Internals' [junction.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) I managed to create such a junction point from 32-bit cmd.exe and launch 64-bit cmd.exe.

Comment: For example, how to check the 64-bit registry from a 32-bit installer:

C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK" /v CurrentVersion