# Invoking 64-bit console from 32-bit python

Tags: python, cmd, 32bit-64bit, os.system

I'm attempting to write a script that will gather the output of a few basic windows commands into a set of files, and am finding my vssadmin commands frustrating. The command is a relatively simple

```
os.system('vssadmin list writers>> x:\foo\vss.txt')
```

The problem is that I'm writing in python 32-bit and want to make sure this will function on 64-bit Windows. When executing this, the return is:

> vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line
>   tool (C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Error: A Volume Shadow Copy Service component encountered an
>   unexpected error. Check the Application event log for more
>   information.

Can I invoke a 64-bit command line from 32-bit python and decide whether to invoke it with a bit-depth detecting function, or is there another more elegant solution?

**Follow-up**: using MBu as a jumping off point I found that the following command does the trick:

```
os.system('%systemroot%\\sysnative\\cmd.exe /c vssadmin list writers > x:\\foo\\vss.txt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows 2008 or newer you can launch `c:\Windows\Sysnative\vssadmin.exe`. Under Windows 2003 a hotfix is needed, but you can also create a filesystem junction to reach the 64-bit system file from 32-bit applications. For details see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453277/how-can-32-bit-cmd-exe-launch-64-bit-cmd-exe-in-windows-2003-x64/). While it was about launching 64-bit cmd.exe from 32-bit cmd.exe, the rules stay the same for all applications.

Answer (score 0):

Launch `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vssadmin.exe` explicitly to always get the 64-bit version.

Comment: That exposes the same error as invoking vssadmin from python. The matrix for this error is:

'Python + syswow64 = Fail
python + system32 = fail
os + syswow64 = fail
os + system32 = proper output'

I've tried this on a number of congruent environments with the same results.